# Función si un dato DateTime tiene más de un mes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de reportes diario en el cual me piden un "Semáforo" de urgencia dependiendo si un equipo tiene un mes sin dar mantenimiento.

La cuestión es que no encuentro forma de obtener las fechas de la base de datos y comparar si estas ya tienen un mes de antigüedad para programar la función, tengo ésto:

```
 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select fecha_mantenimiento from mprev;", con);
        using (MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, con))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adp.Fill(dt);
            dgvmantprev.DataSource = dt;
            string[] desarmar = null;
            string duracion = null;
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dgvmantprev.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    duracion = dgvmantprev.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    desarmar = duracion.Split('/');
                    DateTime oldDate = new DateTime(int.Parse(desarmar[2]), int.Parse(desarmar[1]), int.Parse(desarmar[0]));
                    DateTime newDate = DateTime.Now;

                    if (oldDate.AddMonths(1) < newDate)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Hace falta mantenimiento");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // NO HACE FALTA MANTENIMIENTIO...
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: cual es el SELECT que estas ejecutando ?

Comment: porque iteras las rows de un datagridview para obtener la diferencia entre las fechas? esto no aplica si quieres filtrar con una consulta a la tabla

Comment: Para recapitular lo que Leandro te comenta, porque haces todo esto cuando un simple query a tu db deberia devolverte este dato ya?

Comment: te la complicaste mucho como comentan los compañeros arriba, mejor muestra tu tabla y se hace un query en base a las fechas registradas y obteniendo la fecha actual de mysql usando alguna funcion Now() o la equivalente.

Comment: puedes darle un vistazo a estas funciones de fechas de MySQL http://www.cristalab.com/tutoriales/fechas-con-mysql-c84136l/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si conoces la **última fecha** en la que se realizó un mantenimiento al equipo, lo puedes hacer de esta manera:

```
        // ÚLTIMA FECHA DE MANTENIMIENTO 
        DateTime fechaUltimoMantenimiento = DateTime.Parse("15/01/2020");

        if (fechaUltimoMantenimiento.AddMonths(1) < DateTime.Now)
        {
            // EL EQUIPO TIENE MAS DE 1 MES SIN MANTENIMIENTO
            // NECESITA MANTENIMIENTO.
        }
        else
        {
            // NO HACE FALTA MANTENIMIENTIO...
        }
```

---

**UPDATE**: Según tu código sería algo así dentro del **for**:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < dgvmantprev.RowCount; i++)
            {
                duracion = dgvmantprev.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                desarmar = duracion.Split(':');
                MessageBox.Show("Funciona");
                DateTime oldDate = new DateTime(int.Parse(desarmar[2]), int.Parse(desarmar[1]), int.Parse(desarmar[0]));
                DateTime newDate = DateTime.Now;

                if (oldDate.AddMonths(1) < newDate.Now)
                {
                   // EL EQUIPO TIENE MAS DE 1 MES SIN MANTENIMIENTO
                   // NECESITA MANTENIMIENTO.
                }
                else
                {
                    // NO HACE FALTA MANTENIMIENTIO...
                }
            }
```

Comment: ¿Cómo haría para que esa función se ejecute en cada fila de una base de datos? Es decir, tengo mi base de datos con 1000 equipos, ¿Cómo puedo llevar ese código a todos los equipos para que me regrese si necesita mantenimiento?

Comment: @Yahirmuñoz: Conoces la **fecha de último mantenimiento** de cada equipo?. Si es así, edita la pregunta e indica cual es en el código.

Comment: porque resolverlo desde codigo trayendose todos los registros si se puede obtener solo los que se necesitas con uan query en la db

Comment: Sí, todos los equipos tienen un registro de el último mantenimiento realizado

Comment: La duda que aún tengo es al ejecutar el código que me compartiste, ¿Como lo adapto para ejecutarlo con esos 1000 registros?

Comment: @Yahirmuñoz haces un for. Pero igual esta no deberia ser tu solucion.. nunca.. la db ya itero sobre los registros y trajiste montones que no deberian estar.

Comment: @Yahirmuñoz: En el código que ya tienes dentro del **for**, sustituye `fechaUltimoMantenimiento` del código que te dejé por `oldDate`, que parece que es la fecha de último mantenimiento.

Comment: Me da el error "Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto"

Comment: @LeandroTuttini: Posiblemente lo que quiera es traer todos los registros para verlos en pantalla (los que si requieren mantenimiento y los que no), por eso los pasa a un `dataGridView`. Ya si posterirmente tiene porblemas de rendimiento, se dará cuenta que tiene que realizar **paginación**.

Comment: @Yahirmuñoz: Cuando te de un error, indica siempre donde te ha dado, edita la pregunta e indícalo. Posiblemente tengas registros **sin fecha de último mantenimiento** y la fecha te viene a NULL. Controla eso en el código.

Comment: El error me lo marca exactamente en ésta linea `duracion = dgvmantprev.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();`

Comment: @Yahirmuñoz: Pues parece que no estás recibiendo datos. Que select tienes?, la original `Select fecha_mantenimiento from mprev;` o la que te indicaron. Déjala como la tenías al principio.

Comment: @gbianchi: Posiblemente lo que quiera es traer todos los registros para verlos en pantalla (los que si requieren mantenimiento y los que no), por eso los pasa a un dataGridView. Ya si posterirmente tiene porblemas de rendimiento, se dará cuenta que tiene que realizar paginación.

Comment: Tuve un error anteriormente en la sintaxis del select que corregí en cada ocasión que colocaba el código que me indicaban por eso lo actualicé al correcto pero el que puse recientemente es el Select que debería retornar la fecha de mantenimiento. De igual si es necesario el otro select que tenía era "Select fecha_reporte from reportes"

Comment: @Yahirmuñoz: Edita la pregunta e indica lo que tienes actualmente de código, si no va a ser muy difícil ayudarte.

Comment: Ya está actualizada.

Answer (score 2):

Podria ejecutar una query como ser

```
string query = @"SELECT * FROM reportes 
                WHERE DATE_ADD(fecha_reporte,INTERVAL 5 MONTH) < NOW()";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);

MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adp.Fill(dt);

dgvmantprev.DataSource = dt;
```

Basicamente a la fecha del reporte le sumas 5 meses si esta fecha supera a la fecha del dia entonces se cumplio el plazo

[MySQL DATE_ADD() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp)

Usas las funciones de fecha propias de mysql

Comment: Verificando y ejecutando el comando en mysql no me devuelve ningún valor a pesar de que modifiqué la fecha de mantenimiento a 01/01/2020 y el comando lo dejé en "SELECT * FROM reportes 
                WHERE DATE_ADD(fecha_reporte,INTERVAL 1 MONTH) > NOW()"

Comment: Leandro creo que estamos buscando < a Now ;) si no, solo traerias los que todavia no cumplieron un mes ( y ahi el problema de OP). @Yahirmuñoz proba poner <

Comment: De momento con el operador "<" y ">" sigue sin regresar ningún dato en la consulta.

Comment: Puede ser que aplicara mal la comparacion, pero porque dices `y` para usar los simbolos de mayor o menos? tienes que ser solo una opcion. Ejecutaste la consulta en un management de mysql o lo haces solo desde codigo. Recuerda que toda la logica que luego usas para comparar no aplica

Comment: Me refiero a que lo hice por separado, primero coloqué "SELECT * FROM reportes WHERE DATE_ADD(fecha_reporte,INTERVAL 1 MONTH) > NOW()" y luego "SELECT * FROM reportes WHERE DATE_ADD(fecha_reporte,INTERVAL 1 MONTH) < NOW()" pero sigue sin regresar dato alguno.

Comment: Si ejecutas `SELECT fecha_reporte as FechaReporte, DATE_ADD(fecha_reporte,INTERVAL 1 MONTH) as Fecha1Mes, NOW() as FechaDia FROM reportes` puedes ver que alguna fecha cumple con la condicion de superar la fecha de dia. Ejecutalo en un administrador como ser `mysql workbench` https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Comment: Me aparece que ninguno cumple la función a pesar de que un dato tiene fecha del 01/01/2020 que ya cumpliría el mes.

Comment: entonces algo no estoy entendiendo, si en el campo fecha_reporte tienes un valor de 1/1/2020 y a eso le sumas 1mes entonces la fecha del actual es superior por lo tanto si usas: `now > fecha_reporte + 1mes` deberias tener ese registro

Comment: Ya que cerraron mi pregunta anterior me gustaría su ayuda para poder mostrar los equipos que requieren mantenimiento dependiendo de las fechas que se recopilaron en el mismo código, es decir. Quiero hacer un query a la db para obtener sólo los equipos que sí requieren mantenimiento. Agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: La pregunta que abriste tenia exactamente este mismo codigo, para que planteaste esta pregunta si vas a dejar el codigo tal cual lo tenias en un principio? se supone que si abriste esta pregunta era para mejorar tu codigo, y la seguiente pregunta deberia aplicar las mejoras mas algo adicional que surgiera

Comment: El código lo actualicé, si pudieses checar las demás respuestas y específicamente la que marque como útil es la que aportó a solucionar el problema que tenía. Sí, el código permanece parecido más no es el mismo y la pregunta realizada posterior a ésta era otra duda que tenía.

Comment: ok entiendo, bueno entonces genera la nueva pregunta, aclarando con un link que es una extension de esta, asi queda claro

Answer (score 0):

Se que ya encontraste la solución pero igual comento

```
using (MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection(con))
{
string query = "Select fecha_reporte from reportes"; //yo guardo el query en un string cuestion de gustos
MySqlCommand cn = new MySqlCommand(query, conexion);
cn.CommandTimeout = 60;

//puedes agregar un try aqui
Try
{
DateTime _Reporte = Convert.ToDateTime(cn.ExecuteScalar());

    //Aqui ya agregas un if, como el ejemplo de arriba
    If (_Reporte < DateTime.Now)
    {
    MessageBox.Show("El Equipo Necesita Mantenimiento")
    }
    Else
    {
    //no necesita
    }
}
catch (MysqlException e)
{
MessageBox.Show(e.Message)
}
```

No he usado mucho MySql pero algo así debería funcionar...

Comment: Me da el mismo error que me da en el código de la repuesta anterior "Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto"

Comment: ExecuteScalar que devuelve? este codigo se ve muy raro sobre todo para hacer un select a toda una tabla